# How to find documents older or newer than X in RethinkDB?

Tags: datetime, rethinkdb

I'm trying to query for documents older than 900 seconds, but I'm stuck. This is what I have tried so far:

```
r.table("bar")
  .filter(r.expr(r.now() - 900).gt(r.row("updated_at")))
```

and

```
r.table("bar")
  .filter(r.row("updated_at")
    .during(r.time(1970, 1, 1, 'Z'), r.row("updated_at") - 900))
```

both throw `TypeError: Illegal non-finite number 'NaN'.` for some reason. The following does not, but returns no results:

```
r.table("bar")
  .filter(900 < r.now() - r.row("updated_at"))
```

`updated_at` is a secondary index and holds `RqlDateTime` objects, RDB version is 2.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write `r.now().sub(900)` instead of `r.now() - 900`, because JavaScript doesn't allow you to override the binary operators.

Comment: thank you! originally I translated the query from Python so I could experiment with it in Data Explorer, and this transformation wasn't obvious for me. now it works!